# Populating DATA in the help() call

Tags: python

If I have the following directory structure:

```
handy/
  - __init__.py
  - utils.py
  - dir1
    - __init__.py
    - script.py
```

I can populate `DATA` in `help()` by writing non-keywords into the `__init__.py` file, for example:

```
# __init__.py
hello = "xyz"
other = "z"
variables = 1
```

Now when I do help(handy), it shows:

```
DATA
    hello = 'xyz'
    other = 'z'
    variables = 1
```

Are there any other ways to populate the help `DATA` from outside of the top-level `__init__.py` file, or is that the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you have in mind, but since `handy/__init__.py` is an executable script, you could do something like this:

**`__init__.py`:**

```
from .utils import *
hello = "xyz"
other = "z"
variables = 1
```

**`utils.py`:**

```
UTILS_CONSTANT = 42

def func():
    pass
```

Which would result in:

```
>>> import handy
>>> help(handy)
Help on package handy:

NAME
    handy

PACKAGE CONTENTS
    utils

DATA
    UTILS_CONSTANT = 42
    hello = 'xyz'
    other = 'z'
    variables = 1

FILE
    c:\stack overflow\handy\__init__.py


>>>
```

to what `help(handy)` displays.